# SQL Server Temporal Tables: Can I record specific changes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temporal-tables

I would like to know if I can create a temporal table on a SQL Server database that keeps specific changes.

For example, I have a database that I would like to record any insert/update/delete that is made by a user via SQL Server Management Studio, but I don't want to record changes that are made by an application that interacts with the database.

Comment: Temporal table record all changes. So you're saying if this user made a change through some other client tool like Azure Data Studio, you wouldn't care?

Comment: Generally, I would like to know if there is a possibility to "restrict" what changes records and from what application. But as I understand by your comment, temporal tables keep all changes, from any application.

Comment: Correct. To limit changes from an application, that application needs to specifically set it's name in the connection string. Which is completely optional. So that's quite difficult to ascertain. Regardless, why would you not allow changes through one application but then allow them through another? You can (usually) work out the user using functions like `suser_sname()`. The only way to block changes based on this is use a trigger.

Comment: Does the application use a specific user? You can create a trigger that inspects `suser_sname()` and logs all changes that aren't made by the application user. I'd be suprised if this yields the same user if the same person logs in via SSMS and via an app.